poppler pdf2imagePpython error with idx Google
I'm using Google idx.
When I trying to run this:
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
pages = convert_from_path('./test/yassir.pdf', 1)
for page in pages:
   page.save('out.png', 'PNG')'''
give me this error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/selleniumtest/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 581, in pdfinfo_from_path
    proc = Popen(command, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/nix/store/a667c433yylasy2y2xgisz2jlgnq3pwy-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/nix/store/a667c433yylasy2y2xgisz2jlgnq3pwy-python3-3.10.14/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pdfinfo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/selleniumtest/test/cv.py", line 18, in <module>
    pages = convert_from_path('./test/yassir.pdf', 1)
  File "/home/user/selleniumtest/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 127, in convert_from_path
    page_count = pdfinfo_from_path(
  File "/home/user/selleniumtest/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pdf2image/pdf2image.py", line 607, in pdfinfo_from_path
    raise PDFInfoNotInstalledError(
pdf2image.exceptions.PDFInfoNotInstalledError: Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?

I tried with python-poppler, but it s not working, I want path of pappler bin in Google idx.
